# How can I set the last modified time of a file from python?

Tags: python, unix, last-modified

I have a python script that downloads a file over FTP using [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html).

My current download code looks just like the example in the ftp lib docs:

```
ftp.retrbinary('RETR README', open('README', 'wb').write)
```

Now I have a requirement that the file downloaded over FTP needs to have the same last modified time as the file on the FTP server itself. Assuming I could parse out the time from `ftp.retrlines('list')`, how can I set the modified time on the downloaded file?

I'm on a unix based OS if that matters.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Use [`os.utime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.utime):

```
import os

os.utime(path_to_file, (access_time, modification_time))
```

More elaborate example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_utime.htm

Comment: this answer could be improved with an example and discussion of the format of that time; specifically an epoch; IE @jossef's answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for dates before 1980 on Windows, correct? (Why do I wanted to set date modified before 1980, you ask? Because that's what Google Photos uses when I drag files in).

Comment: Actually I think the value IS being set for dates before 1980. It's just blank when viewed in Windows File Explorer.

Comment: In case someone only wants to update the "last modifed" date to the current time, simply calling ```os.utime(path_to_file)``` does the job.

Answer (score 51):

To edit a file last modified field, use:

```
os.utime(<file path>, (<access date epoch>, <modification date epoch>))
```

Example:

```
os.utime(r'C:\my\file\path.pdf', (1602179630, 1602179630))
```

> - Epoch is the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970. [see more](https://www.epochconverter.com/)

---

If you are looking for a `datetime` version:

```
import datetime
import os

def set_file_last_modified(file_path, dt):
    dt_epoch = dt.timestamp()
    os.utime(file_path, (dt_epoch, dt_epoch))

# ...

now = datetime.datetime.now()
set_file_last_modified(r'C:\my\file\path.pdf', now)
```

> - For Python versions < 3.3 use `dt_epoch = time.mktime(dt.timetuple())`

Comment: Thank you for this answer; it contains examples, is detailed and helpful.

Comment: This should have been the answer. but it is 8 years late

Answer (score 21):

There are 2 ways to do this.  One is the [`os.utime` example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38754092) which
is required if you are setting the timestamp on a file that has no
reference stats.

However, if you are copying the files with `shutil.copy()` you have a
reference file.  Then if you want the permission bits, last access time,
last modification time, and flags also copied, you can use
`shutil.copystat()` immediately after the `shutil.copy()`.

And then there is `shutil.copy2` which is intended to do both at once...