# How to modify the file modification date with python on mac?

Tags: python, metadata

Title says it all. I am trying to modify the file modification dates of folders. `touch t- YYYYMMDDhhmm` command from terminal does it, but it also changes the file creation date, which I do not want to change.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: If I run `touch test2` I get a new file with today as modified/created date (in Finder Get info), as expected.  Then running `touch -m -t 200001010000 test2` sets both the created and modified date to the year 2000, which is what you observed but seems like a bug.
If I then run it again with new date `touch -m -t 222201010000 test2` it modifies ONLY the modification date, which is the expected behavior!  I think it is a bug on Apple's part.  Seems like an omission that the `touch` utility doesn't have an Created Date option by itself.
Should file a bug report.

Comment: @bnaecker That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!

Comment: Related question: [How can I set the last modified time of a file from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11348953/14928633)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`os.utime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.utime) can be used to change the modification and/or access time of a file.

It accepts a descriptor or path-like object, and a tuple of times in either seconds or nanoseconds. These specify the latest access and modification times, respectively. For example:

```
>>> import os
>>> with open('tmp', 'wt') as f: pass
...
>>> result = os.stat('tmp')
>>> print(result.st_atime, result.st_mtime)
1541131715.0 1541131715.0
>>> os.utime('tmp', (result.st_atime, result.st_mtime + 1.0))
>>> result = os.stat('tmp')
>>> print(result.st_atime, result.st_mtime)
1541131715.0 1541131716.0
```

Comment: Unless I'm reading the answer wrong, this doesn't answer how to stop Python from changing the created time, which seems to be a side-effect of using `utime`

Comment: Are you referring to the `st_ctime` field? At least on Unix platforms, that's not the "created time". From the documentation of [`os.stat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=utime#os.stat_result.st_ctime), that is the time of the most recent metadata change.