# Set folder timestamp with Python

Tags: python, timestamp

I'm writing a script that processes files in directories, but I want the directories' timestamps to remain the same. So I want to get the timestamp before the operation, then set in back after.

Getting the timestamp is easy enough (`os.path.getmtime()`), but I can't seem to find an equivalent `set` method.

Any suggestion?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348953/how-can-i-set-the-last-modified-time-of-a-file-from-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use os.utime().

Should work fine.

Define variables with date, time and stuff before so the actual setting function doesn't get that cluttered.